# Clarification on the -h Flag for Makecert.exe

Tags: certificates, windows

When using Microsoft's Makecert.exe to generate a certificate (and key), there is the option to allegedly "specify the maximum height of the tree below that certificate", using the -h flag (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

As an experiment, I created a certificate with "-h 0", assuming this to mean that this certificate in turn could not be used to generate another (adding to the chain). I then went on to attempt creating a subsequent certificate, and to my surprise all went well.

I can't find anything further explaining the usage of the flag on MSDN or anywhere else. Can one of you please enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some further investigation and realized that this constraint is taken into account at the time of *resolving* the certificate chain of trust, not at the time of creating a new link. From  [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#page-39):

> The pathLenConstraint field [...]. In this case, it gives the
> maximum number of non-self-issued intermediate certificates that may
> follow this certificate in a valid certification path. [...] A pathLenConstraint
> of zero indicates that no non-self-issued intermediate CA certificates may
> follow in a valid certification path. [...] Where pathLenConstraint does
> not appear, no limit is imposed.

See also [TechNet - Understanding Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737026%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).